# KendoUI Tabstrib Select First Tab on all

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a page that contains several kendoUI tabstrips, the problem I am encountering is that I want to select the first tab of all the tabstrips that are on the page. The code I have currently works for the first tab strip however not for any of the tabstrips after that point.

I am trying to avoid using the list class `<li class="k-state-active">` to set the initially active tab.

Currently this is the code I have:

```
$(".tabstrip").kendoTabStrip({
    animation: {
        open: {
            effects: "fadeIn"
        }
    }
}).data("kendoTabStrip").select(0);
```

I am using a class instead of an ID because there are multiple tabstrips that are dynamically created based on a datasource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use jQuery `each` as follow:

```
$(".tabstrip").each(function(idx, elem) {
    $(elem).kendoTabStrip({
    animation: {
        open: {
            effects: "fadeIn"
        } 
    }
    }).data("kendoTabStrip").select(0);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 var tabStrip = $("#testing_tabs").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");
 tabStrip.select(0);
```

Comment: In my case I had to set timeout for 800ms for line tabStrip.select(0);  to get it work. Any solution for this issue?